# Remove spaces from Auto-mount mountpoint

Tags: mount, raspbian, automounting, block-device

Is it possible to remove spaces from auto-mount mount point label?

For example:
If insert a thumb drive that has the name `"Device Name With Spaces"` it should auto-mount to `/media/DeviceNameWithSpaces` and not `/media/Device Name With Spaces`

I'm running Raspbian desktop version on a Raspberry Pi